# Yarn install Invariant Violation: should have a resolved reference

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, yarnpkg

I'm attempting to build a release on Jenkins 2.150.1 and I'm encountering an error with yarn install:
`Invariant Violation: should have a resolved reference`

The install works fine on my local machine with the same configuration.

Does anybody know how I might resolve this?

```
verbose 0.446 Checking for configuration file "/usr/.yarnrc".

verbose 0.45 current time: 2019-06-05T03:51:11.266Z

[1/4] Resolving packages...

verbose 1.179 Performing "GET" request to
"https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ember-cli-babel".

verbose 1.286 Request "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ember-cli-babel"
finished with status code 200.

warning Resolution field "ember-cli-babel@6.12.0" is incompatible with
requested version "ember-cli-babel@^5.1.6"

warning Resolution field "ember-cli-babel@6.12.0" is incompatible with
requested version "ember-cli-babel@^5.1.6"

warning Resolution field "ember-cli-babel@6.12.0" is incompatible with
requested version "ember-cli-babel@^5.1.6"

warning Resolution field "ember-cli-babel@6.12.0" is incompatible with
requested version "ember-cli-babel@^5.1.6"

verbose 1.435 Invariant Violation: should have a resolved reference

  at invariant (/opt/yarn/lib/cli.js:1296:15)

  at PackageRequest.resolveToExistingVersion (/opt/yarn/lib/cli.js:34819:51)

  at PackageResolver.resolvePackagesWithExistingVersions (/opt/yarn/lib/cli.js:60937:11)

  at /opt/yarn/lib/cli.js:60869:14

  at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

  at step (/opt/yarn/lib/cli.js:92:30)

  at /opt/yarn/lib/cli.js:103:13

  at <anonymous>

  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

error An unexpected error occurred: "should have a resolved
reference".

info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the
information provided in "/usr/src/app/yarn-error.log".

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation
about this command.

time="2019-06-05T03:51:12Z" level=fatal msg="build failed: building
[myapp-client]: build artifact: running build: The command '/bin/sh
c yarn --ignore-engines install --verbose' returned a non-zero code: 1"

script returned exit code 1
```

Relevant Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.9.4-stretch as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
COPY .npmrc .
COPY yarn.lock .
COPY .bowerrc .
COPY bower.json .
RUN yarn cache clean
RUN yarn --ignore-engines install --verbose

COPY . .
RUN yarn run build:production
```

Comment: Somewhat related: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discovered this was due to the CI server's yarn version.

Downgraded to version 1.3.2 locally and was able to replicate the issue.

Upgraded to yarn 1.16 and the issue disappears.

Solution: upgrade yarn:

```
sh "curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | sh"
```